# Calling a Method Once

Tags: java, android, methods

I am having a problem of how to call a method once when the condition achieves many times! for example:

```
public void onLocaitonChanged(Location location){

  // this if statement may achieve the condition many times
  if(somethingHappened){

       callAMethodOnce();// this method is called once even if the condition achieved again
  }

}
```

Please help with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void onLocaitonChanged(Location location){

  // this if statement may achieve the condition many times
  if(somethingHappened){

       if (!isAlreadyCalled){   
           callAMethodOnce();// this method is called once even if the condition achieved again
           isAlreadyCalled = true;
       }
  }

}
```

Comment: Consider use `AtomicBoolean` if multithreaded.

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean isHappendBefore = false;

public void onLocaitonChanged(Location location){

  // this if statement may achieve the condition many times

  if(somethingHappened && (! isHappendBefore) ){
       isHappendBefore = true;
       callAMethodOnce();// this method is called once even if the condition achieved again
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply set a flag. If you just need it to only happen once with each instance of the `Activity` then set a member variable.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
     boolean itHappened = false;

     ...

    public void onLocaitonChanged(Location location)
   {

      // this if statement may achieve the condition many times
      if(somethingHappened && !itHappened)
      {
           callAMethodOnce();// this method is called once even if the condition      achieved again
           itHappened = true;
      }   
   }
```

If you want it to only happen once ever in the life of the application then set that variable as a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 1):

set a class wide boolean

```
if(!hasRun){
    callAMethodOnce();
    hasRun = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question correctly but from your problem definition I would suggest using a boolean variable something like.

```
boolean run = false;
public void onLocaitonChanged(Location location){

  // this if statement may achieve the condition many times
  if(somethingHappened && run == false){
        run = true;
       callAMethodOnce();// this method is called once even if the condition achieved again
  }

}
```

Once the code under `if` statement gets executed once `run` would be `true` and there won't be any subsequent calls to `callAMethodOnce()`

Comment: run should be outside onLocaitonChanged