# Call a method once, only if button is clicked (atleast once)

Tags: javascript, jquery, buttonclick

I would like to call `loadNext()` method only once, if any of the other buttons are clicked at least once.

I have checked out: [Calling a Method Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150558/calling-a-method-once)

For example, I am making a quiz app, having question and some options for each question types.
User will select an option and hit on next button to load the next question(with options), (those are predefined in an array). `loadNext()` shouldn't be called multiple times even if the options are clicked more than once (to prevent this I avoided calling `loadNext()` inside onclick method of those options(buttons), and also wont load if none of the options are selected,

and my idea is something like pre-defining `isClicked` as `false`, and inverting inside onclick method of those options, but that is not working.

What I have done, so far:

[image: question_and_options]

```
var optButtons = $(".opt button");
var isClicked = false;
optButtons.click(function () {
        isClicked = true;
        console.log("clicked on opt buttons: " + this.id);
        console.log("Current button is: " + this.id + " set as active");
       //other stuffs
    });

//some other stuffs


if (isClicked) {
console.log("Clicked once!");
        //other stuffs
        loadNext();
    } else {
        alert("Please select an option");
//browser is alerting very first time after opening `index.html` file 
// and Next button click isn't working after that
        }
```

Any instruction will be appreciated, thanks in advance!
I am new in JS.

Comment: You need an onclick handler for the next button that checks if( isClicked ) - could be even cleaner to just check the state of the other buttons when you click next instead of tracking the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something of the sort, assuming you have an `id="next"` for your Next button

```
$("#next").on('click',function(){
    if(isClicked){
        loadNext();
        // Set isClicked to false to reset mechanism
        isClicked = false;
    }
});
```

Would this be what you' re looking for ? I understood it this way

Comment: checking `isClicked` state inside the onclick of next button is doing the job! thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

you are logging to console when the option buttons are clicked, and that is Ok, but in the onClick listener for the next button, check if the only one option is clicked or not.. and you can create a variable in global scope to check how many
times the next button is clicked, code snippet is

```
//function called on clicking the next button
function abcd(){

  counter++;
  if(counter!=-1){
   return;
  }
  else{
    //call the loadnext()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have your answer with radio buttons. You can try 'radio buttons' for the options. There are enough and more references online. Please let me know if that doesn't suit your requirement.

Comment: For Reference, try this; https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_radio.asp